# Weird CSS background-image url when inspecting facebook image

Tags: css, facebook, background-image

This url syntax is weird to me when I inspect an image from facebook. Can anyone explain how it can be displayed normally? If I right click then open the link in new tab, the link won't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is just the colon “escaped” in CSS syntax.

See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes#identifiers-strings for details on the syntax.

`\3a` is the hex code for `:` in that notation, and space after it is just a sort of “delimiter” to signal this escape sequence ends here.

Quote from above site:

> Theoretically, the `:` character can be escaped as `\:`, but IE < 8 doesn’t recognize that escape sequence correctly. A workaround is to use `\3A` instead.

---

Not sure why Facebook would do this here in the first place though, can’t think of any technical reason of the top of my head, because `:` should not be problematic in such a place (specifying a background image URL) per se.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the string with below

"3a"--->  ":"

"\3d" --->> "="

"\26"---> "&"

" "---> ""  (empty space with no space)